# How to do scroll control in flutter by passing the data fetched from api as pageno

Tags: flutter, scroll

How to make scroll control by sending the next page parameter as pageno in url. I have url where I am sending the pageno as pageno='', and to get the next page I need to pass the data which is returned from the future fetchpost. For example I have initial url as 
"https://example.org/api.php&action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pilimit=max&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$pageno where pageno=''

and second url to get next page content is

https://example.org/api.php&action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pithumbsize=600&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$pageno

where pageno='some string value'.

I have written code but the when I scroll to the end of the page I am passing next page data to url and it wipes out the data of first page and displays next page page content list on it instead continuing with the list below the firstpage.

Below is my code please help me with the issue.

```
class Herbs extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  Herbs(this.title);

  @override
  _HerbsState createState() => new _HerbsState();
}

class _HerbsState extends State<Herbs> {
  List<Herbslist> herbslist = [];
  var cname;
  var gcm;
  var pageno = '';
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
     fetchPost(pageno);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() {
          pageno = gcm;
          fetchPost(pageno);
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<Herbslist> fetchPost(String pageno) async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://example.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=600&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$pageno'
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if(this.mounted){
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        gcm = jsonData["continue"]["gcmcontinue"];
      }
    } else {
      print(Exception);
      throw (e) {
        print("Exception thrown: $e");
        Exception(e);
      };
    }
    return Herbslist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cname = widget.title;
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-0.2, 0.3),
            child: Text(
              cname,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Herbslist>(
            future: fetchPost(gcm),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.query.pages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    var img = snapshot.data.query.pages.values.toList()[index].thumbnail.source;
                    return Container(
                        child: Card(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Detailpage(
                                  snapshot.data.query.pages.values.toList()[index].title,
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        leading: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            border: new Border(
                                right: new BorderSide(
                                    width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey)),
                          ),
                          child: img == img.isEmpty
                              ? SizedBox(height: 50.0,width: 50.0,child: Image.asset('images/ayurwiki.png'),)
                              :SizedBox(
                            height: 50.0,
                            width: 50.0,
                            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              placeholder: 'images.png',
                              image: img,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          )
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                            snapshot.data.query.pages.values.toList()[index].title),
                      ),
                    )));
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Herbslist.dart

```
 class Herbslist {
     String batchcomplete;
     Continue herbslistContinue;
     Limits limits;
     Query query;

     Herbslist({
         this.batchcomplete,
         this.herbslistContinue,
         this.limits,
         this.query,
     });

     factory Herbslist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Herbslist(
         batchcomplete: json["batchcomplete"],
         herbslistContinue: Continue.fromJson(json["continue"]),
         limits: Limits.fromJson(json["limits"]),
         query: Query.fromJson(json["query"]),
     );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
         "batchcomplete": batchcomplete,
         "continue": herbslistContinue.toJson(),
         "limits": limits.toJson(),
         "query": query.toJson(),
     };
 }

 class Continue {
     String gcmcontinue;
     String continueContinue;

     Continue({
         this.gcmcontinue,
         this.continueContinue,
     });

     factory Continue.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Continue(
         gcmcontinue: json["gcmcontinue"],
         continueContinue: json["continue"],
     );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
         "gcmcontinue": gcmcontinue,
         "continue": continueContinue,
     };
 }

 class Limits {
     int categorymembers;
     int pageimages;

     Limits({
         this.categorymembers,
         this.pageimages,
     });

     factory Limits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Limits(
         categorymembers: json["categorymembers"],
         pageimages: json["pageimages"],
     );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
         "categorymembers": categorymembers,
         "pageimages": pageimages,
     };
 }

 class Query {
     Map<String, Page> pages;

     Query({
         this.pages,
     });

     factory Query.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Query(
         pages: Map.from(json["pages"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Page>(k, Page.fromJson(v))),
     );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
         "pages": Map.from(pages).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
     };
 }

 class Page {
     int pageid;
     int ns;
     String title;
     Thumbnail thumbnail;
     String pageimage;

     Page({
         this.pageid,
         this.ns,
         this.title,
         this.thumbnail,
         this.pageimage,
     });

     factory Page.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Page(
         pageid: json["pageid"],
         ns: json["ns"],
         title: json["title"],
         thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? Thumbnail(source:'',width:0,height:0) : Thumbnail.fromJson(json["thumbnail"]),
         pageimage: json["pageimage"] == null ? null : json["pageimage"],
     );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
         "pageid": pageid,
         "ns": ns,
         "title": title,
         "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : thumbnail.toJson(),
         "pageimage": pageimage == null ? null : pageimage,
     };
 }

 class Thumbnail {
     String source;
     int width;
     int height;

     Thumbnail({
         this.source,
         this.width,
         this.height,
     });

     factory Thumbnail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Thumbnail(
         source: json["source"],
         width: json["width"],
         height: json["height"],
     );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
         "source": source,
         "width": width,
         "height": height,
     };
 }
```

Comment: You have list of Herblist. It's a bit confusing. Can you share your Herblist class too?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the list you have. You need to append new data into your list.

Your logic should be like this:

```
// Declare a list
List<Herbslist> herbslist = [];

// Update the list
herblist.add(Herbslist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)));

// Return the updated list
return herblist;
```

Without further information about your `Herblist` class, I can't guarantee that this would work. You probably need to flat you *List of Lists*.

**Update**

Your data structure seems unconvinient for this situation. There are better ways to structure your data and respresent it on the UI. You wrapped iterable data into a class and whenever you get new instance from that class you end up with having two different data stores. Since you pass the newest instance to the UI, only the latest results will show up on the list.

You should have a single data store (eg. a list or map for your API results) and append new data into it. You only have model classes now. They should declare **how** is your data structured. They shouldn't store any real data.

Comment: How to structure the data so that I can make list instead of map. Can you please help me.

Comment: You should have model classes that represents atomic data. Then you can use some iterable container like List<Data> to represent multiple atomic data instead of having a class called DataList.

Comment: Use Flutter's gitter or discord channel to reach me for further talk.

Comment: Still my issue is not solved, I reached you on gitter,